# Does the activity in IPL count by ICC?

Tags: cricket, statistics, icc, records, indian-premier-league

I want to know, if a player takes wicket, scores runs etc. in IPL (Indian Premier League), will it be counted by **ICC** (In their record/history)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The International Cricket Council ([ICC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Cricket_Council)) is the international governing body of cricket.

IPL is one of the domestic cricket competitions held [in India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_domestic_Twenty20_cricket_competitions#India). It's not an [international T20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twenty20_International) cricket series. The performances(runs scored, wickets taken etc) will not be counted for any [ICC awards](http://www.icc-cricket.com/lg-icc-awards) or for any [ICC rankings](http://www.relianceiccrankings.com/). But those IPL stats will be added to the [Twenty 20 career](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/records/index.html?class=6) of the cricket players but not to the [Twenty 20 internationals](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/records/index.html?class=3).

Not only IPL, all the domestic as well as international T20 activities will be added to the Twenty 20 career of respective players. For example, if you see the runs scored by [Chris Gayle](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/records/284267.html) in Twenty 20 matches, it will include the runs that he scored for West Indies and for other domestic teams like Jamaica Tallawahs, Kolkata Knight Riders, Royal Challengers Bangalore etc.

You can also refer [this post](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1785/career-of-a-cricketer) about the difference between Twenty 20 and T20I.

Comment: Might be useful to include the difference between Twenty 20 and T20I in the answer itself, because (1) it saves time reading some other web-page (2) the web-links can change Dynamically, so the information might not be available later.